# Programming: Scala drawing a card from a deck until its empty

Tags: scala

im trying to make a deck in scala. I Have two enumerators of my information: "Suit" and "Face". I have a following code that handles deck class:

```
case class Card (suit: Suit, face: Face) //require("error") nereikia net naudoti cia, nes object naudojam

  class Deck(myCards: List[Card] = for(face <- Face.all; suit <- Suit.all) yield Card(suit, face))
  {
    val cards = if(myCards.size > 0 && myCards.size <= 52) myCards
    else throw new Exception("Nepavyko sukurti kortu kalades!")

    val shuffledCards = util.Random.shuffle(cards)

    val drawCard = (cards.head, cards.tail)
    val splitShuffled = if(myCards.size % 2 == 0) shuffledCards.sliding(26, 2).toList
    else throw new Exception("Kortu kiekis negali buti nelyginis, nesazininga!")
  }
```

How do i cycle threw my deck and draw each card? Basically i have a brand new deck and then with function splitShuffled i split my deck in two smaller decks for two players. How do i compare each drawn card with each other? That's the most frustrating thing about functional programming to me. I don't get it! How is one suppose to cycle threw these cards if my list is immutabale? :D Thank you so much for help!! ^^

Comment: Please phrase the question and its title in a way that they have something to do with programming, not with cards (you should abstract from what you are doing, so other people can be helped when they see your question)

Comment: What do you mean by "compare each drawn card with each other"? Please give more detail on what you are actually trying to achieve. Also, I don't think the `sliding` call is doing what you think it is

Comment: The nested `for`-comprehension does not belong into the default argument, move it into companion object, or create a second constructor. Most of the stuff inside the `Deck` doesn't seem to belong there either. Is this supposed to be a class describing a deck of cards, or is it supposed to be the control flow immediately following the entry point of the program? I also don't see a single function value, so I'm not sure what this has to do with FP. Looks like good old OOP.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm new to functional programming.. Basically im trying to make a game of war, each player has 26 cards and each turn they draw one card from the top of the deck. Then you compare these two cards and higher ranked card wins - that player takes both cards and puts them in a different pile. If ranks are equal both players put their cards into their own score piles. Who ever has most cards in their score pile wins. I come from OP scene so it is really hard for me to adjust to this. What am i doing wrong here? How should i separate these functions to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first time I solved this problem so it's probably not perfect, but it should give you some ideas. I think it's a nice exercise to practice FP.

I like to think of types first, and then of transformations (functions) I need in order to arrive at the solution. Finally, small functions can be composed if types align.

Since you haven't given definitions for `Suite` and `Face` I defined them as follows (used `Rank` instead of `Face` though):

```scala
sealed trait Suit
sealed case class Hearts() extends Suit {
  override def toString = "♡"
}
sealed case class Diamonds() extends Suit {
  override def toString = "♢"
}
sealed case class Clubs() extends Suit {
  override def toString = "♧"
}
sealed case class Spades() extends Suit {
  override def toString = "♤"
}

sealed class Rank(val value: Int) {
  override def toString = s"${value}"
}
sealed case class Ace() extends Rank(14) {
  override def toString = "A"
}
sealed case class King() extends Rank(13){
  override def toString = "K"
}
sealed case class Queen() extends Rank(12){
  override def toString = "Q"
}
sealed case class Jack() extends Rank(11){
  override def toString = "J"
}
sealed case class Ten() extends Rank(10)
sealed case class Nine() extends Rank(9)
sealed case class Eight() extends Rank(8)
sealed case class Seven() extends Rank(7)
sealed case class Six() extends Rank(6)
sealed case class Five() extends Rank(5)
sealed case class Four() extends Rank(4)
sealed case class Three() extends Rank(3)
sealed case class Two() extends Rank(2)

case class Card(suit: Suit, rank: Rank) {
    override def toString = rank.toString+suit.toString
}
```

`toString` methods are only there to make debugging output more concise.

I also created two type aliases for readability:

```scala
type Deck = List[Card]
type Hand = List[Card]
```

Two functions to generate a list of of suits and ranks:

```scala
def suits(): List[Suit] = List(Hearts(), Diamonds(), Clubs(), Spades())
def ranks(): List[Rank] = List(Ace(), King(), Queen(), Jack(), Ten(), Nine(), Eight(), Seven(), Six(), Five(), Four(), Three(), Two())
```

And a deck:

```scala
def deck(): Deck = for (
  s <- suits();
  r <- ranks()
) yield Card(s, r)
```

Now, to the more interesting parts. Shuffle takes a `Deck` and returns a new (shuffled) `Deck`:

```scala
def shuffle(cards: Deck): Deck = util.Random.shuffle(cards)
```

`divide` takes a `Deck` (a `List[Card]`) and returns two `Hand`s (a `(List[Card], List[Card])`):

```scala
def divide(cards: Deck): (Hand, Hand) = cards.splitAt(cards.length / 2)
```

For the scoring function I introduced a new family of types to model a battle result:

```scala
sealed trait BattleResult
sealed case class Player1Wins(cards: List[Card]) extends BattleResult
sealed case class Player2Wins(cards: List[Card]) extends BattleResult
sealed case class War(cards: List[Card]) extends BattleResult
```

The `score` function itself will take two cards, but also cards from the previous battle (the war scenario). It will compare the cards and return a result:

```scala
def score(player1Card: Card, player2Card: Card, previousTurnCards: List[Card] = List()): BattleResult = (player1Card.rank.value - player2Card.rank.value) match {
  case s if (s == 0) => War(player1Card :: player2Card :: previousTurnCards)
  case s if (s > 0) => Player1Wins(player1Card :: player2Card :: previousTurnCards)
  case s if (s < 0) => Player2Wins(player2Card :: player1Card :: previousTurnCards)
}
```

Finally, the `battle` function. What's important here is to handle stop cases (when one of the hands is empty), and call `battle` recursively until we're done:

```scala
def battle(player1Hand: Hand, player2Hand: Hand, previousTurnCards: List[Card] = List()): (Hand, Hand) = (player1Hand, player2Hand) match {
  case (p1, List()) => (p1, List())
  case (List(), p2) => (List(), p2)
  case (nextCard1 :: remainingCards1, nextCard2 :: remainingCards2) => score(nextCard1, nextCard2, previousTurnCards) match {
      case Player1Wins(cards) => (remainingCards1 ::: cards, remainingCards2)
      case Player2Wins(cards) => (remainingCards1, remainingCards2 ::: cards)
      case War(cards) => battle(remainingCards1, remainingCards2, cards)
  }
}
```

In case `Player1Wins` we add cards to the end of their pile. 
In case `Player2Wins` we do the same with player2's pile. 
In case of `War` we `battle` again.

Last, but not least, the `play` function which will keep playing until there's a winner:

```scala
def play(hands: (Hand, Hand)): (Hand, Hand) = hands match {
  case (h, List()) => (h, List())
  case (List(), h) => (List(), h)
  case (player1: Hand, player2: Hand) => play(battle(player1, player2))
}
```

Execute:

```scala
play(divide(shuffle(deck())))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer, but here are some tips on how you might do this:

---

First create a class that represents the data for one `Player`. This contains a **draw** pile, a **score** pile and a `score` method that calculates the score for that player.

Next you create a class that represents the current `State` of the game. This contains two instances of `Player` and perhaps some other data. It also has a method that compares the `score` for each player and indicates who is the `winner` (or a tie).

Then you create a function that plays one round of the game. It takes the current `State` and generates a new `State` which contains the result of playing one round. This would take the `head` of each **draw** pile and compare the two cards. It then generates two new **score** piles based on this comparison, and two new **draw** piles which are just the `tail` of the current **draw** pile. The new `State` is created using two instances of `Player` created with the new **draw** and **score** piles.

You then write a recursive function that takes the initial `State` and generates the result of a single round. If the **draw** piles are now empty it returns the new `State`, otherwise it recursively calls itself with the new `State`.

Calling `winner` on the result of this function (the final state) will tell you who won the game.

---

This is a brief description of how it might be done but the crucial thing is that there is no mutable state anywhere, just a set of pure functions that take immutable values and return immutable values.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Def helped! ^^